# Sips: resize image's smallest side, not largest side

Tags: macos, terminal, image-processing, sips

The command `sips -z 2000 image.jpg` will resize the biggest side of an image to 2000 if it is greater than 2000, while preserving the original aspect ratio.

Is there a similar command that will resize the smallest side of an image to 2000 if it is greater than 2000, while preserving the original aspect ratio?

The rationale behind this request is that if I try to downsize the greatest side of an image to 2000, it will greatly affect the resolution of panoramas and other long/wide images.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently using ImageMagick [yields more favorable results](https://retifrav.github.io/blog/2019/12/12/imagemagick-vs-sips-resize/) when compared to `sips`, so using ImageMagick instead might be better. The command to do so is:

```
convert image.jpg -resize '2000x2000^>' image-resized.jpg
```

The `2000x2000^` resizes the image so that its shortest side is at least 2000 pixels. So, for example:

```
6000x4000 → 3000x2000
4000x6000 → 2000x3000
```

The `>` character prevents it from acting upon images that would be upscaled, and as a result:

```
600x400 → 600x400
8000x1500 → 8000x1500
```